# NSUserdefaults for multiuser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

In my application, I am using a login form to enter into the application, also using `NSUserDefaults` to store user preferences, for example:

```
[storeData setObject:self.loginField.text forKey:@"USEREMAIL"]; 
[storeData setObject:self.PasswordField.text forKey:@"PASSWORD"];
```

Like I stored, if a new user logs in the NSUserDefaults stored value will be changed. But I want both preferences (ex:new userid and old userid as well as password). So please explain how to store multiple values for same key?

Comment: store the passwords and usernames in an `NSMutableDictionary` which contains multiple `NSMutableDictionary` objects and save that object to the user defaults.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first download and import files of given link

https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security

then where u want to store user preferences write this code

[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:loginField.text andPassword:PasswordField.text forServiceName:@"dhaya" updateExisting:YES error:&error];

where u want password write this code

NSString *password = [SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:loginField.text andServiceName:@"dhaya" error:&error];
   NSLog(@"passwordpassword %@",password);

this will working great....

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this would be to store a NSDictionary with UserIDs as keys and the passwords as values.

---

Another option is to use [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) as it specifically designed for this kind of thing and is also more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Global `NSMutableArray` and add above details in `NSDictionary` Objects and Store all Objects in array.This way you will have all user objects.You can get it whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

first of all create global array with AppDelegate class, for example..

```
userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"arrScheduleDates"];
if (dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch != nil) {
    NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingtblArrayForSearch];
    if (oldSavedArray != nil)
        arrScheduleDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
    else
        arrScheduleDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
} else {
    arrScheduleDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
[arrScheduleDates retain];
```

after that when you want to store the new record then get all record from `arrScheduleDates` array and after that add the new record and after that store like whole array like above..

i hope you understand and its helpful for you...

:)

Answer (score 0):

The absolute easiest way to meet your requirements is to use the user's email address (assuming they're all unique) as the storage key for your dictionary, and the password as the value.

If you need to store more than the password, then the value of the key would be another dictionary with keys and values for the user.

An example of the simple case would look similar to :

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *storedUsers = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"userData"];
if (nil == storedUsers) storedUsers = [NSDictionary dictionary];

NSMutableDictionary *mutableStoredUsers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:storedUsers];
NSString *userPassword = [self.PasswordField.text copy]; //add autorelease if you aren't using ARC
NSString *userEmail = [self.loginField.text copy]; //add autorelease if you aren't using ARC
if (nil != userEmail)
{
  [mutableStoredUsers setObject:userPassword forKey:userEmail];
}

[userDefaults setObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutableStoredUsers] forKey:@"userData"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```